How to resolve RouteEnhancerInterface error - D9.5?
It seems impossible to upgrade. I need to upgrade a couple sites from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 en route to Drupal 10. In upgrading from Drupal 8.9 to Drupal 9 the composer part works fine. However, afterwards, attempts to use Drush to clear cache or to run drush updb are responded to with:
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Drupal\entity_browser\Routing\CtoolsFallbackRouteEnhancer' not found in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() (line 259 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'entity_browser.ctools_fallback_route_enhancer') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('entity_browser.ctools_fallback_route_enhancer', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 273)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'router.no_access_checks') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('router.no_access_checks', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'router') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('router', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'router_listener') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('router_listener') (Line: 105)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object) (Line: 127)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

I've read a couple dozen posts on this, including [>=8.5] Fix RouteEnhancerInterface deprecation errors where Wim Leers and Gábor Hojtsy were both involved, but so far none have provided a workaround.

There is no question here but I’ll ask one: Is there an ancient version of ctools installed? https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/issues/2922297

I've changed the title to a question :-)
CTools is 4.1

That file in that version does not reference the class in question. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/ctools/-/blob/4.1.0/src/Routing/Enhancer/WizardEnhancer.php?ref_type=tags#L13. You have not actually installed 4.1 or you somehow installed two copies of ctools. But I'm just guessing. This "two copies" problem was commonly-reported when Composer introduced opt-in for plugins, which updates config.allow-plugins in composer.json. When the composer/installers plugin would be disabled, some people ended up with additional core or module installs in the vendor directory.

I'm updating and posting the entire message. It seems to be called from entity_browser.

No. You've changed the question entirely. It's probably old code. There isn't much else to go on here.

Changing the question is allowed, as long as the question does not have answers that are invalidated.

I was pointing out that the OP changed the question rather than posting the entire message, which is what their comment said. I didn't say it was disallowed to do so.

It's an old version of Entity Browser. The missing service in the error message was removed 5 1/2 years ago:
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-02-12/issue-2764875-81-reroll.patch
diff --git a/entity_browser.services.yml b/entity_browser.services.yml
index 769092d..07eb215 100644
--- a/entity_browser.services.yml
+++ b/entity_browser.services.yml
@@ -20,11 +20,6 @@ services:
   entity_browser.route_subscriber:
     class: Drupal\entity_browser\RouteSubscriber
     arguments: ['@entity.manager', '@plugin.manager.entity_browser.display', '@entity.query']
-  entity_browser.ctools_fallback_route_enhancer:
-    class: Drupal\entity_browser\Routing\CtoolsFallbackRouteEnhancer
-    arguments: ['@module_handler']
-    tags:
-      - { name: route_enhancer }

diff --git a/src/Routing/CtoolsFallbackRouteEnhancer.php b/src/Routing/CtoolsFallbackRouteEnhancer.php
deleted file mode 100644

See https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser/issues/2764875
You need to update Entity Browser and you can uninstall Ctools if you don't need it for other modules (see required by on the Extend page). Do this before you upgrade core.

you were correct. What actually was happening was that the ssl cert for the domain had expired, and the default config for ssl requests was sending them to a folder that was D8.
